# SSD, SSHD, HD - what to use for imaging backups?

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive

What I want to do is to hook up a 2.5" drive via USB 3 (I have no eSATA) (notebook is ivy bridge so my understanding is it is probably an H77 motherboard - Inspiron 7720SE 17R i5-3230M)

So I'm not sure where the bottlenecks are.. USB3 or the sustained read/write speeds of the HD?

What I want to do with this external drive is to backup (via imaging technology - something like Acronis, still didn't decide on which software to use... probably not full backups always, but perhaps like a full backup every weekend and incremental daily)

My question is.. would there be any benefits using an SSHD over an HD? SSD would be great but only has 1/4 the capacity at the price levels I'm looking at...

basically my choices are:

- Seagate Desktop HDD 1TB 3.5" SATA3 64MB Cache OEM Hard Drive (ST1000DM003)
- Seagate Laptop SSHD 1TB 2.5" 5400RPM 64MB Cache Solid State Hybrid Drive (ST1000LM014)
- ADATA 240GB SSD - forget the exact model, specs look fairly typical ~500mbps but some reviews say it runs "dog slow"

my gut tells me that for full backup SSHD would give no advantage over a regular HD.. but does it have some advantages on the smaller, incremental backups?

Comment: Both are your limitations equally

Comment: You have identified your limitations. Speed and cost vs storage space.  We can't really tell you which one is better for your situation. Personally I would rather spend a little more money and get a decent sized SSD but of course this is just my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the drive is solely for backups, then you should prefer storage space over speed.

SSDs are faster at data throughput in general, but they really shine when it comes to heavy I/O load on random reads.  Backups are a mostly sequential write operation.  Given that the price per GB is much higher, I'd avoid it for backups.  It'd be more expensive and you'd be wasting its potential.

SSHDs are a similar story.  They are a normal spinning hard drive with a small SSD cache so that in the best case scenario, they can perform as fast as an SSD can.  In the worst case scenario, they're only as fast as an ordinary hard drive.  The SSD cache will not benefit you at all for backups and SSHDs are more expensive than HDDs.

A traditional HDD is your best choice.  It won't be as fast as an SSD, but you can buy them in multi-terabyte capacities for a fraction of the cost of an SSD.

With a standard HDD, it's true that your full backups will take a lot longer.  But the incrementals will probably go quick regardless of which drive type you choose.

Comment: I didn't read the specs closely enough, the SSHD I listed is only 5400 RPM, kinda stupid

Comment: oh... you mean that the sustained read/write speeds are pretty close to SSD on regular HDs? So probably for me with the USB3 only connection, it would work out basically the same...

Comment: No, SSDs can write faster than HDDs too, but the disparity is greater (i.e. hard drives are slightly faster at reading than writing, but SSDs are WAY faster at reading than writing).

Comment: And yes, most SSHDs are only available in 5400RPM speeds whereas 7200RPM is an option for most HDDs.  So in the worst case scenario, an SSHD is actually slower than a 7200RPM HDD.

Comment: Low-end SSDs don't write much faster than HDDs. SSHDs will be of no use because SSHDs only benefit reads, not writes, regardless of RPM. Unless you're backing up *from* an SSD your source drive is more likely to be the bottleneck